# How to run Flask on EC2 Amazon?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have done all steps. When I run application I see console message:

```
[ec2-user@ip publisher]$ python __init__.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 111-801-147
```

My question how to make this script public, that user able to see interface?

I have Public DNS, IPv4 Public IP

I use Cent OS

Comment: Which steps exactly ? you need to use a reverse proxy with a WSGI server (uWSGI, gunicorn, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you instance is reachable from the internet (public subnet of a VPC), make the the server listen on `0.0.0.0`. Currently it listens to the local requests only.

After making the change, instead of:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

you will see:

```
Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```